# Wrong table of contents numbering on the right side

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

How can I fix the obviously wrong numbering at the right side of the sections?

This is what it looks like now (left: corect, right: wrong):
[image: Screenshot Latex]

This is my minimal example code for this section (I don't wanted to shorten it more because I don't know if this effects the potential solution):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage[subfigure,titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}

% Quotes
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize, captionpos=b, breaklines=true, showstringspaces=false, tabsize=2, frame=lines, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, xleftmargin=2em, framexleftmargin=2em}
\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1em}{\hspace{1,5em} Lst. #1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\geometry{a4paper, top=27mm, left=30mm, right=20mm, bottom=35mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}

\hypersetup{unicode=false, pdftoolbar=true, pdfmenubar=true, pdffitwindow=false, pdfstartview={FitH},
    pdftitle={ABC},
    pdfauthor={ABC},
    pdfsubject={ABC},
    pdfcreator={\LaTeX\ with package \flqq hyperref\frqq},
    pdfproducer={pdfTeX \the\pdftexversion.\pdftexrevision},
    pdfkeywords={ABC},
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=black}
\pdfinfo{/CreationDate (D:20110620133321)}

% subsubsubsection via paragraph ---> Makes x.x.x.x for paras
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
% END

\begin{document}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

% Kopf- und Fusszeile
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}{\rightmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thesection\space\contentsname}
\lfoot{abc}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\ \linebreak Seite \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Vorspann
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\Roman{section}}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Abstract
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{page}{1}
\onehalfspacing
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{2pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\rhead{Vorwort \& Kurzfassung}

\section{Vorwort}

lksajdlksajd

\section{Kurzfassung}

sajdalskdlsajd

\vspace{-1,2em}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\section*{Abstract}

sldsaldlsdkl

\pagebreak

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Verzeichnisse
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TODO Typ vor Nummer
%\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tab. }
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Abb. }
\settowidth{\cfttabnumwidth}{Abb. 10\quad}
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Abb. 10\quad}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{2pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\singlespacing
\rhead{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{III Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\texorpdfstring{III Inhaltsverzeichnis}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}}
\addtocounter{section}{1}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\rhead{Verzeichnisse}
\listoffigures
\pagebreak
%\listoftables
%\pagebreak
%\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Listing-Verzeichnis}
%{\labelsep2cm\lstlistoflistings}
\pagebreak

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Abkürzungen
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym} % längste Abkürzung steht in eckigen Klammern
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep} % geringerer Zeilenabstand
    %\acro{API}{ - Application Programming Interface}
\end{acronym}
\newpage

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Inhalt
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Abstände Überschrift
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

% Kopfzeile
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\lhead{Kapitel \thesection}
\rhead{\rightmark}

\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Einleitung
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Einleitung}

dfödjdöjfödkjf


\pagebreak

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Literatur
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand\refname{Quellenverzeichnis}
\bibliographystyle{myalpha}
\bibliography{bib1}
\pagebreak

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Anhang
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\lhead{Anhang \thesection}

\end{document}
```

I have already tried to comment a few lines out, or used `\addtocounter{section}{1}` (what only manipulates the left side..)  but nothing helps.
Thanks for your support folks :)

Comment: why do you say the numbers are "obviously wrong" ? That is not at all obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Your code breaks almost all KOMA-Script feature. Do not use a KOMA-Script class with packages `titlesec`, `tocloft`, `parskip`, `fancyhdr` ... There are other strange things too.

So I would suggest to the standard class `article` (or maybe better `report`). Then you can use package `tocbibind` for the numbered ToC and lists with entries in ToC.

With package `tocloft` you can use `\cftpagenumbersoff{section}` and `\cftpagenumberson{section}` to switch the page numbers in ToC off and on.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=27mm, left=30mm, right=20mm, bottom=35mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
  \tocsection
  \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}%
  \endgroup}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
  \tocsection
  \tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}%
  \endgroup}
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\begingroup
  \tocsection
  \tocfile{\contentsname}{toc}%
  \endgroup}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[subfigure,titles]{tocloft}
\addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{.5em}% enlarge the space for the section numbers

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[naturalnames]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}
\section{Vorwort}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Kurzfassung}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{section}}
\section{Einleitung}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]